# Shortcut to switch between tabs in different rows

Tags: sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, code-editor

When I have two tabs in differenet rows (after doing `View -> Layout -> Rows: 2`) - Is there a shortcut (or a way to create one) to switch between these two?

Like `Ctrl + Tab` is switching between two tabs in the same column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View -> Focus Group -> Next` menu item will switch between them. Like all menu items, the relevant keybinding is shown on the right hand side.

If you want to use a different key combination, you can open the ST Console (`View -> Show Console`) and type `sublime.log_commands(True)` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and execute that menu item again to see what command and arguments it uses. Then, it's just a matter of editing your user keybindings accordingly.